# How to simulate a remote server that has a different public IP address?

Tags: linux, email, vpn, web-server, virtual-machines

I'm trying to set up 2 remote servers, each connected to the internet through their dedicated ISP router. In order to self-host email+web services and many more. My goal is to make them able to DNS failover, thanks to a site-to-site VPN tunnel between them, used for heartbit exchange and choosing who is the master and who is the slave.

Before affording costly hardware, I would like to experiment by installing and configuring all the pieces of software, and make a 2nd fictionnal remote server communicate with my 1st VM. To do so, I would use :

- my current linux laptop by spinning a virtual linux machine on it, that
- I would connect to my ISP router through some ports and thus making it inherit of my public IP address.

In addition,

- Since I would prefer not to subscribe to a 2nd ISP for getting a different router (with a different public IP address),
- and since I don't have found yet relatives from whom I could benefit plugging another physical machine to their ISP router

Would it be possible to configure a second VM on my laptop running side by side with the first one but having another public IP address ? Do you guys know explanatory ressources for that please?

Comment: How about to spawn two vm in different regions at DigitalOcean on AWS? A simple test will cost just couple of bucks.

Comment: thank you very much for this idea, I will go for it if no one knows how to do it for free with one laptop/free services